# My PC does not react to power on button, only direct key

Tags: windows-10, boot, shutdown, desktop-computer, debug

When I press the power on button (applies to both the one on the mainboard(!) aswell as the one on the case), nothing happens, neither shutdown, when on, nor startup, when off.

The only way I can start it is by pressing direct key, after which the PC will power on and then restart multiple times. Powering off only works by pressing shutdown in Windows.
The PC worked before in this configuration.

Does this mean that something on the mainboard is damaged? Or are there other possible reasons for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

try Holding power button down from 10-30 seconds to see if that helps also check BIOS and check if you've made any power changes in Windows such as do nothing when told to sleep also make sure that you are shutting the computer down proberly and if it is rebooting multiple times it may be trying to do a software update